# Add Header to OpenXML Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I'm working on as asp.net webform that when completed the user needs to download a word document that will summarize the answers that they chose.  I've successfully done this with saving html as a .doc but now the client would like .docx.  I've been able to successfully generate a document that they can download but for the life of me I can't get a header to show up.

One thing that seems a little off is if I use the Open SML productivity tool a document that I create in word will have /word/header1.xml 2 and 3 tags, my documents will just have /word/header.xml.  But I can't figure out how to change that.

Here's all the code I've been using:

```
public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument(string filepath)
{
    // Create a document by supplying the filepath. 
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(filepath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        // Add a main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
        AddSettingsToMainDocumentPart(mainPart);

        // Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = new Document();

        HeaderPart headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId7");
        GenerateHeader(headerPart);

        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Testing text"));
    }
}

private static void GenerateHeader(HeaderPart part)
{
    Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 w15 w16se wp14" } };
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx2", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx3", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx4", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx5", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx6", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx7", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("cx8", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("aink", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("am3d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w15", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w16se", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
    header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

    Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00B22010", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00B22010" };

    ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
    ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

    paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

    Run run1 = new Run();
    Text text1 = new Text() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
    text1.Text = "This is a ";

    run1.Append(text1);

    Run run2 = new Run();
    Text text2 = new Text();
    text2.Text = "header";

    run2.Append(text2);
    BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart() { Name = "_GoBack", Id = "0" };
    BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd() { Id = "0" };

    paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
    paragraph1.Append(run1);
    paragraph1.Append(run2);
    paragraph1.Append(bookmarkStart1);
    paragraph1.Append(bookmarkEnd1);

    header1.Append(paragraph1);
    part.Header = header1;
}

private static void AddSettingsToMainDocumentPart(MainDocumentPart part)
{
    DocumentSettingsPart settingsPart = part.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>();
    settingsPart.Settings = new Settings(
       new Compatibility(
           new CompatibilitySetting()
           {
               Name = new EnumValue<CompatSettingNameValues>(CompatSettingNameValues.CompatibilityMode),
               Val = new StringValue("16"),
               Uri = new StringValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word")
           }
       )
    );
    settingsPart.Settings.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ludovic Perrichon (http://www.ludovicperrichon.com/) helped me find an answer for this one.  While we didn't get my code to work the code here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355228(v=office.12).aspx
does work and allows me to generate a header with the new document.

Slightly modified from the link above:

```
public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument(string filepath)
{
    string documentPath = filepath;

    using (WordprocessingDocument package =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(
        documentPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        AddParts(package);
    }
}

private static void AddParts(WordprocessingDocument parent)
{
    var mainDocumentPart = parent.AddMainDocumentPart();

    GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainDocumentPart);

    var documentSettingsPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart
        <DocumentSettingsPart>("rId1");

    GenerateDocumentSettingsPart().Save(documentSettingsPart);

    var firstPageHeaderPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId2");

    GeneratePageHeaderPart(
        "First page header").Save(firstPageHeaderPart);

    var firstPageFooterPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("rId3");

    GeneratePageFooterPart(
        "First page footer").Save(firstPageFooterPart);

    var evenPageHeaderPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId4");

    GeneratePageHeaderPart(
        "Even page header").Save(evenPageHeaderPart);

    var evenPageFooterPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("rId5");

    GeneratePageFooterPart(
        "Even page footer").Save(evenPageFooterPart);

    var oddPageheaderPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("rId6");

    GeneratePageHeaderPart(
        "Odd page header").Save(oddPageheaderPart);

    var oddPageFooterPart =
        mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>("rId7");

    GeneratePageFooterPart(
        "Odd page footer").Save(oddPageFooterPart);
}

private static Document GenerateMainDocumentPart()
{
    var element =
        new Document(
            new Body(
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Text("Page 1 content"))
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new LastRenderedPageBreak(),
                        new Text("Page 2 content"))
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new LastRenderedPageBreak(),
                        new Text("Page 3 content"))
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new LastRenderedPageBreak(),
                        new Text("Page 4 content"))
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })
                ),
                new Paragraph(
                    new Run(
                        new LastRenderedPageBreak(),
                        new Text("Page 5 content"))
                ),
                new SectionProperties(
                    new HeaderReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.First,
                        Id = "rId2"
                    },
                    new FooterReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.First,
                        Id = "rId3"
                    },
                    new HeaderReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even,
                        Id = "rId4"
                    },
                    new FooterReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even,
                        Id = "rId5"
                    },
                    new HeaderReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default,
                        Id = "rId6"
                    },
                    new FooterReference()
                    {
                        Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default,
                        Id = "rId7"
                    },
                    new PageMargin()
                    {
                        Top = 1440,
                        Right = (UInt32Value)1440UL,
                        Bottom = 1440,
                        Left = (UInt32Value)1440UL,
                        Header = (UInt32Value)720UL,
                        Footer = (UInt32Value)720UL,
                        Gutter = (UInt32Value)0UL
                    },
                    new TitlePage()
                )));

    return element;
}

private static Footer GeneratePageFooterPart(string FooterText)
{
    var element =
        new Footer(
            new Paragraph(
                new ParagraphProperties(
                    new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" }),
                new Run(
                    new Text(FooterText))
            ));

    return element;
}

private static Header GeneratePageHeaderPart(string HeaderText)
{
    var element =
        new Header(
            new Paragraph(
                new ParagraphProperties(
                    new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" }),
                new Run(
                    new Text(HeaderText))
            ));

    return element;
}

private static Settings GenerateDocumentSettingsPart()
{
    var element =
        new Settings(new EvenAndOddHeaders());

    return element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've automated this process of creating Headers and Footers using OpenXML in my OfficeIMO C# Library (MIT licensed) with support for Different Odd and Event Pages, Different First Page and support for sections to the point where it's just as easy as this:

```cs
document.AddHeadersAndFooters();
document.DifferentOddAndEvenPages = true;
document.DifferentFirstPage = true;
```

full code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OfficeIMO.Word;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;

namespace OfficeIMO.Examples.Word {
    internal static partial class HeadersAndFooters {
        internal static void Example_BasicWordWithHeaderAndFooter0(string folderPath, bool openWord) {
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Creating standard document with Headers and Footers");
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, "Basic Document with Headers and Footers Default.docx");
            using (WordDocument document = WordDocument.Create(filePath)) {
                document.AddHeadersAndFooters();
                document.DifferentOddAndEvenPages = true;
                document.DifferentFirstPage = true;

                document.Header.Default.AddParagraph().SetColor(Color.Red).SetText("Test Header");

                document.Footer.Default.AddParagraph().SetColor(Color.Blue).SetText("Test Footer");

                Console.WriteLine("Header Default Count: " + document.Header.Default.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Header Even Count: " + document.Header.Even.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Header First Count: " + document.Header.First.Paragraphs.Count);

                Console.WriteLine("Header text: " + document.Header.Default.Paragraphs[0].Text);

                Console.WriteLine("Footer Default Count: " + document.Footer.Default.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Footer Even Count: " + document.Footer.Even.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Footer First Count: " + document.Footer.First.Paragraphs.Count);

                Console.WriteLine("Footer text: " + document.Footer.Default.Paragraphs[0].Text);

                document.Save();
            }

            using (WordDocument document = WordDocument.Load(filePath)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Header Default Count: " + document.Header.Default.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Header Even Count: " + document.Header.Even.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Header First Count: " + document.Header.First.Paragraphs.Count);

                Console.WriteLine("Header text: " + document.Header.Default.Paragraphs[0].Text);

                Console.WriteLine("Footer Default Count: " + document.Footer.Default.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Footer Even Count: " + document.Footer.Even.Paragraphs.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Footer First Count: " + document.Footer.First.Paragraphs.Count);

                Console.WriteLine("Footer text: " + document.Footer.Default.Paragraphs[0].Text);

                document.Save(openWord);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

- [OfficeIMO GitHub Page](https://github.com/EvotecIT/OfficeIMO)